# Elm type confusion

Tags: elm

I started on my first, simple web app in Elm. Most of my code is currently adapted from https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example. I am working against a API that will give me a authToken in the response header. I have a AuthToken type that is supposed to represent that token. Taking the value out of the header and converting it to a result that's either a error `String` or a `AuthToken` is causing trouble. I expected that I could just say I am returning a AuthToken, return a String and it would be fine because my AuthTokens right now are just Strings. It seems like there clearly is something about Elm types I am not understanding.

Here is the definition of `AuthToken`:

```
type AuthToken
  = AuthToken String
```

and my way too complicated function that for now just tries to do some type changes (later I want to also do work on the body in here):

```
authTokenFromHeader : String -> Http.Response String -> Result String AuthToken
authTokenFromHeader name resp =
    let
        header = extractHeader name resp
    in
    case header of
        Ok header ->
            let
                token : Result String AuthToken
                token = Ok (AuthToken header)
            in
            token
        Err error -> Err error
```

I expected the happy case would return a Ok result with the string from the response header converted to a `AuthToken` as its value. Instead I am getting `Cannot find variable 'AuthToken'`. From the documentation I expected to get a constructor with the same name as the type. If I just use `Ok header`, the compiler is unhappy because I am returning `Result String String` instead of the promised `Result String AuthToken`.

What's the right approach here?

Comment: just to be sure that `AuthToken` is visible, do you have `type AuthToken` definition in the same file or have it exposed from some imported module?

Comment: @IgorDrozdov is right, you should expose the type constructor in the module where you define AuthToken `module X.AuthToken exposing (AuthToken(..))` and also where you import the module `import X.AuthToken exposing (AuthToken(..))`. Side remark: what's also confusing (although not incorrect) is that you define `header` twice (once as Result in the let binding and once as a String in your case pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks fine as is. The error message indicates that `type AuthToken` has been defined in a different module and not imported completely to the module that defines `authTokenFromHeader`. You can read about Elm's module system in the Elm guide: [Modules](https://guide.elm-lang.org/reuse/modules.html).

A possible fix, assuming that `type AuthToken` is defined in module `Types`, and `authTokenFromHeader` is defined in module `Net`, is:

Types.elm:

```
module Types exposing (AuthToken(..))

type AuthToken = AuthToken String
```

Net.elm:

```
module Net exposing (authTokenFromHeader)

import Types exposing (AuthToken(..))

authTokenFromHeader : String -> Http.Response String -> Result String AuthToken
authTokenFromHeader name resp =
    ...
```

Note the use of `AuthToken(..)` instead of just `AuthToken`, which ensures that the type as well as the type constructors are imported/exported.

Or just move the definition of `type AuthToken` into the same file as the definition of `authTokenFromHeader`.

Comment: Thanks! I was importing and exposing them but was missing the `(..)`. Every time I saw these I assumed those were indicating that the example was abbreviated till I noticed how consistently you, @dvekeman and the docs were using these.

Comment: Good! I updated the answer slightly to explain the importance of `(..)`.